# Prove a statement with elements for Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am stuck on this proofing question and I would like some clarification.

Q: $A\subseteq B \iff A\cap B^{\prime} = \emptyset$

I already proved that LHS goes to RHS, but I am confused for the other way around because the textbook answer key gives a weird answer.

It says that for $A\cap B^{\prime}=\emptyset$, let $x$ be an element of $A$. **If x isn't an element of $B$** then, then $x$ is an element of $B^{\prime}$, therefore $x$ is an element of $A\cap B = \emptyset$. **Hence $x$ is an element of $B$** and $A$ is a subset of $B$.

I am mainly confused about how they say $x$ isn't an element of $B$ and then all of a sudden say $x$ is an element of $B$...? How could it be both an element and not an element of $B$??

Comment: $\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align}\quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1\quad &\quad\text{"#2"}\\ \quad &}
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}$Not an answer, but I would prove both directions together:
$$\calc
\langle\forall x::x\not\in A\cap B'\rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{definitions of $\;\cap\;$, $\;'\;$}
\langle\forall x::\lnot(x\in A\land x\not\in B)\rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: DeMorgan}
\langle\forall x::x\not\in A\lor x\in B\rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: rewrite}
\langle\forall x::x\in A \Rightarrow x\in B\rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\subseteq\;$}
A\subseteq B
\endcalc$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that there's a contradiction here; this is how a standard [proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction) goes: Start by assuming something (that is hopefully false), and use it to get something you *know* is false. Then the original statement must be false too.

So to clarify the proof, I'll expand it a bit:

> Suppose, intending a contradiction, that $x \in A$ but $x \notin B$. However, this implies that $x \in B^c$, so that $$x \in A \cap B^c = \emptyset$$
>   This is the desired contradiction, so $x$ couldn't have existed to start with. Thus if $x \in A$, we have $x \in B$ too, so that $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: For IFF statements don't you wanna prove that either side logically implies the other?

Comment: Yes, you need to prove both parts. I didn't prove the left-to-right direction because you said you already did it.

Comment: Yes, but you said that the other case around that I am having trouble with is a proof by contradiction, so I am proving that it doesn't logically imply? I guess what I am trying to get at is that my textbook has always done direct proofs with iff staements and I've never seen a  proof by contradiction for one.

Comment: @user3718584 I don't understand what your comment is asking - I was trying to clarify how the answer key you have proves the right-to-left statement.

Comment: Well to be specific, was proof by contradiction the only way of proving it?

Comment: @user3718584 There is more than one way to prove a statement. You can try direct proofs (in which you try to derive the proof via only your hypothesis and other proven theorems) and you can try indirect proofs. The most common indirect proofs are _proof by contradiction_ (which goes as T. Bongers explained) and _proof by contrapositive_ (contrapositive: $(p\Rightarrow q) \iff (¬q \rightarrow ¬p)$)